# Git merge: ours+their mixture, ignoring conflicts. Possible?

Tags: git, merge

I'm wondering if I can tell git to resolve conflicts by appending "their" code blocks after "ours".
Does he "know" at all about C-language code blocks ?

Example:

```
//====== ours ======
....
if(cond1)
{
    do_smth();
}
....

//====== their ======
....
if(cond2)
{
    do_smth_else();
}
....
```

Normally such a merge results in a conflict which I would like to resolve *automatically* as :

```
//======= merge result ========
if(cond1)
{
    do_smth();
}

if(cond2)
{
    do_smth_else();
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that flagging this as a conflict seems like an annoyance, but it is by design.  Consider the following situation, you add:

```
if( cond1 || cond2 )
{
   perform_action1();
}
```

and they add:

```
if( cond1 )
{
   perform_action1();
}
```

The portion that they added probably does not match what you were trying to accomplish. If their code were appended to yours, then `perform_action1()` would be called twice.

In short, there is no way to merge automatically because the few times it would be a bad idea, it would be a *really* bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm afraid that git's merge algorithms don't understand the structure of C programs, nor any other programming language.  There are [options to git's recursive merge strategy for automatically resolving conflicting hunks in favour of `ours` or `theirs`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6160214/223092), but as far as I know there is no such option to automatically include both.

Answer (score 0):

You can using the `union` [gitattribute](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

> union
>
> Run 3-way file level merge for text files, but take lines from both
>      versions, instead of leaving conflict markers. This tends to leave the
>      added lines in the resulting file in random order and the user should
>      verify the result. Do not use this if you do not understand the
>      implications.

As @Greyson says, it's not a good idea for C code, though.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33662787/2341735) to a similar question for an example.